# Reading excel file using plsql

Tags: excel, oracle, csv, plsql

Is there any easy way to load data from excel to oracle table? Actually the data in the excel is in denormalized format,
So i need to read row wise and insert into different tables. Is there any direct way exist in PLSQL to read data from excel?
Most of the blog I read they suggest to convert it into csv format.

But when I tried to convert the excel file into csv format, the no of rows in the excel(23787) and csv(23658) are different. So there must be some rows where the
conversion is not proper, So I can not take the risk of converting the file into csv format.

Please suggest.

Comment: Try load data in your temporary table as is then convert. SQL Developer can do this.

Comment: Try this https://technology.amis.nl/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/as_read_xlsx.txt.